# Facebook doesn't see my opengraph meta tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've build a community using rails 3.2, ruby 1.9.3, mongoid and it's all hosted on heroku on a cedar stack - www.Meer.li.

The problem I have now, is that facebook doesn't register my opengraph meta tags at all! I've tried to run it through - http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmeer.li%2F - and it doesn't even see them. I'm at a total loss here and can't find any answers.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your page, you have your Open Graph object `type` set to *activity* as shown below:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="activity" />
```

No Open Graph object schema exists for this type, which is likely the source of your problem. You can verify that here: http://graph.facebook.com/schema/og/activity.

Some common Open Graph object types have been pre-defined, and are documented at http://ogp.me/#types. Alternatively, you may define custom objects with custom attributes by creating a new object type of your choosing, and these should be namespaced in the form `my_namespace:my_type`.

I would recommend trying one of the predefined object types, such as *website*. Assuming that that fixes your problem, but you require more custom behavior, then move on to defining a custom, namespaced object type with custom fields of your choosing.

Comment: It was a good suggestion, but it still doesn't work. It doesn't even register the meta tags (if you look at the scraped URL). I'm thinking it might have something to do with the .li domain? I can't see any other reason for this.

Comment: I took another look at your page, and see a few additional problems: (1) Try removing the image snippet shown below, since [http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg](http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg) is returning a 404. (2) Ignoring the errors for the `xmlns:og` and `xmlns:fb` tags, try fixing the HTML errors detected by the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org). I noticed you have an unclosed `div` and a stray `script` end tag. (3) Lastly, the `og:url` value should be self-referencing. Good luck.

Comment: Did all of your good advices and my site is now validating, except the xmlns:og. Still no cigar with facebook! The only thing facebook sees in the header is this: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head> - take a look at the debugger at: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmeer.li

Comment: I am really at a loss here. I have absolutely no idea how to trouble-shot this one. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could it be one of my gems or the .li domain causing problems?

Comment: While I wouldn't expect the domain to be the problem, I suppose it can't be ruled out. What is strangest is that the debugger seems to show an old, cached version of your site.  When you try rescraping in the debugger, do you see the request from 'facebookexternalhit' in your access logs?

Comment: Ya... I see this in the debugger: 2012-05-09T18:32:19+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 69.63.190.245 - - [09/May/2012:18:32:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 206 4675 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" meer.li

Comment: How can you see it takes an old cached version of the site?

Comment: My apologies, I misspoke. I thought that Facebook may have been caching an old version of the site, since selecting [See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fmeer.li%2F) returns a version of your site with an entirely different doctype and content. However, this does not appear to be the problem. I retrieved your site via command-line using `wget 'http://meer.li/'` and see a very stripped-down version of the site, without the doctype, metatags, head / body tags, etc. I expect that explains why FB is missing your tags.

Comment: That's very weird. Can you tell me why you only get a very stripped down version of my site? This seems to be the cause of the problem for facebook, won't you say?

Comment: If I look at the facebook debugger on the link: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=Meer.li%2Fdesigns%2Fselect-your-car.html - then it gives me some correct meta tags, but it seems to be a bit random. Notice I can't have http:// in the front and have to add .html in the back for it to give me another result. This seems really weird!